# How to fix Octave symbolic package error in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, octave

I have installed the symbolic package. There are some python related errors in the command window of Octave when I try to use symbolic.Below is the output:

```
> pkg load symbolic
>> syms a
Symbolic pkg v2.9.0: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 28, in <module>
AttributeError: '_PrintFunction' object has no attribute '__globals__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in octoutput_drv
  File "<stdin>", line 54, in octoutput
  File "<stdin>", line 55, in octoutput
AttributeError: module 'sympy' has no attribute 'compatibility'
Closing the Python communications link.

error: Python exception: AttributeError: '_PrintFunction' object has no attribute '__globals__'
    occurred in python_header import block.
    Try "sympref reset" and repeat your command?
    (consider filing an issue at https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/issues)
error: called from
    pycall_sympy__ at line 191 column 5
    valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
    assumptions at line 82 column 7
    syms at line 97 column 13
>> Opening in existing browser session.
```

Any idea how i can troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error is a known bug (https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/issues/1035)

You need to use an older version of sympy sunch as version 1.5.1